# different 'apply' methods in RHive API

Tags: r, mapreduce, hive

RHive API contains 5 'apply' functions:

```
rhive.napply
rhive.sapply
rhive.mrapply
rhive.mapapply
rhive.reduceapply
```

Unfortunately, RHive manual does not provide any description

what is the difference between them?

please, help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found partial answer in this brilliant manual:

```
http://www.slideshare.net/miloveme/r-hive-introduction


• napply : R apply function for Numeric type
• sapply : R apply function for String type
```

also, I went to RHive source code here:

```
https://github.com/nexr/RHive/blob/master/RHive/R/rhive.R#L76
```

I found, that rhive.mapapply and rhive.reduceapply just call for rhive.mrapply inside.

rhive.mrapply is generic function for map-reduce applying, and rhive.mapapply/reduceapply are "syntactic sugar"

Examples of rhive.mapapply usage are here:

```
https://github.com/nexr/RHive/blob/master/RHive/inst/unitTests/runit-rhive.script.R
```